# How to change permissions of ntfs partitions?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, fstab

I have this directory:

```
/second -> with "/dev/sdc2" partition.
```

I've used the file /etc/fstab to mount it:

```
/dev/sdc2 /second auto defaults 0 0
```

When I try to change its permissions using "chmod" or "setfacl" there are no changes (just to clarify, I'm using root privileges, obviously).

What am I doing wrong?

I`ve got another partition using ext4 as file system and it works when I try to change permissions.

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful? [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: Read `man mount` - there are options (for `/etc/fstab`) that can adjust the behavior. Also, disable "Fast Boot" on the Windows side.

Comment: Microsoft formatted partitions do not support ownership & permissions. You set a default set when you mount it. And best to use more than just defaults. One example: `windows_names,nosuid,noatime,async,big_writes,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0113,dmask=0022`